# npx create-react-app myapp doesn't work. Aborting installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, npm, create-react-app

When tried create new project
**npx create-react-app my-app** - got this Aborting installation.

[image]

I have node **v14.17.1**
And then I switched the latest version **16.4.0**, and the problem is the same.

[image]

`sudo npm cache clean --force` not resolved my problem

I am reinstalled nvm, but it is not helped. My OS is **macOS Big Sur Version 11.4**
I am a first-time face up with this problem.

[image]

Why I got error **500** on the server https://nexus.poynt.com...?

But now I get another error
[image]

I tried on my old machine Windows 7 and node v13.14.0 and all finish success, the problem with this Mac.

Comment: _"the problem is the same"_ - is it? One says `@types/zipcodes@^7.14.5` can't be resolved (which indeed doesn't seem to exist: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/zipcodes, see Versions tab), the other that there was a server error trying to hit what is presumably your corporate package repo. And please post text **as text**.

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved! I cleared all data in file `~/.npmrc` from the previous project.

**`sudo nano ~/.npmrc`**